# How to make a rotated image fill available space in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, transform

I'm trying to display an image as a rounded diamond shape. I can get the rotations to work and if I use debugPaintSizeEnabled it shows the diamond shape, but the image won't fill that space. How can I get it to expand to fill the diamond?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

This is the code that creates the diamond widget:

```
Transform.rotate(
        angle: math.pi / 4,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: - math.pi / 4,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage("img/kitten_200_1.jpeg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: try rotatedbox.

Comment: That had the same problem. Pavel's solution worked, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `Transform.rotate` doesn't affect child's sizing and positioning — it changes how the child is painted only.

2) Because there is no image data in white "triangles" at your screenshot, to fill them with image we should scale the image up. But then it will overlap neighbor widgets, so we will also scale the diamond down.

```
double L = 100; // image side length
double R = 24; // rounding radius
double k = sqrt(2) - R / L * 2 * (sqrt(2) - 1); // a little bit of geometry
```

Now scale!

```
Transform.rotate(
  angle: pi / 4,
  child: Transform.scale(
    scale: 1 / k,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(R),
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: - pi / 4,
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: k,
          child: Image(
            image: ...,
            width: L,
            height: L,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to rotate the image widget by quarters, you can use RotatedBox which performs this automatic sizing for you: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html